# How to use dispatch_async in swift

Tags: swift

```
func get_data_from_server() {
    let urlPath = NSString(format:"url")
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let data : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
    var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
    var jsonResult: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary
    if (jsonResult != nil) {
        if let image_id_array : NSArray! = jsonResult?.valueForKey("Result")?.valueForKey("id") as? NSArray {
            self.id_array = image_id_array   
        }
        if let description_Array = jsonResult?.valueForKey("Result")?.valueForKey("description") as? NSArray {
            self.description_array = description_Array
        }
        if let img_array = jsonResult?.valueForKey("Result")?.valueForKey("image") as? NSArray {
            self.images_array = img_array
        }
    }
}
```

How to use dispatch_async in swift. I'd like to load an image from a URL in my application

Comment: I would say in the same way as you use it in objc. What problem are you having?

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/making-network-request-swift

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code to load your image from a URL like this

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default_icon"];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = image;
    });
});
```

you should use main queue for change UI only not for Download image.

Comment: That's the opposite of what you should do.

Comment: use global_queue for download image from url and main_queue for change  UI.

Answer (score 0):

Add the whole method of downloading images and add it to array in the following box:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     // add you code here
}
```

Comment: That's incorrect - you shouldn't download data on the main queue.

Comment: @AaronBrager: i have just answer your question about how to use dispatch_async in swift..thats it.

Comment: It's not my question.

Comment: @AaronBrager: can you please give me more details about question?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this for async request...

```
let url = NSURL(string:"http://juzhotel.com/smartcreatives/catholic_app/app/index.php/webservices/getCatholicHighlight")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
 {
    (response, data, error) in

         if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
             let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode
             if statusCode == 200 {
                        // Yes, Do something.
              let resstr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
               println("Data Reriving %@",resstr)
             }
          }

  }
```

Its working fine in my code